# iOS app entered background and still in background for more hours without killing

Tags: ios

I have searched a lot on this but unfortunately, couldn’t find a fruitful answer. Can anyone help me on the below?

In my app, I have three simple ViewControllers and currently I am in `ThirdViewController`. Whilst, if I receive a phone call, automatically my app will go to background and `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate would be called.

Then, if I forget to open or kill my app which is in background and after 8 hours, if I try to open it from background, it is not resuming from `ThirdViewController` instead it is relaunching from `LaunchScreen`.​

**My question:**

1. I would like to understand the reason behind this (my app not resuming from `ThirdViewController` instead it is relaunching from `LaunchScreen`)
2. While my app is in background will there be any communication between my app and iOS. If yes, how I can handle it through my app?
3. But, **within 15 mins**, if I re-open app from background, how App gets maintained Application state, that is showing `ThirdViewController`?
4. If my app is in background for some hours, at that time application states not get maintained. How that Application states get cleared? Either in App level or OS level.
5. If yes, how to handle this?

PS: I don't want to go for `UserDefaults` or other `persistence` storage concepts.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: You have to write code in applicationWillEnterInForeground app delegate method and you have to use UserDefaults, otherwise how do you get to know user on which view controller?

Comment: The app state should be preserved when coming back from background, unless your code explicitly makes changes. However if you app gets killed while in background, then it will restart at its initial state,

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground

you should read the doc carefully, it states that the developer is responsible for preserving the application state. And  in some cases, the application processes will terminate processes for other applications.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623063-applicationdidreceivememorywarni 

you can free memory with this method that is available

Comment: you can communicate your app and device via - [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW8) before we start in here you need to understand the [Strategies for Handling App State Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)

Comment: iOS can kill your app anytime to free memory, what you should use is state restoration, please find more details here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Comment: “I don't want to go for UserDefaults or other persistence storage concepts” ... I’m afraid your going to have to. And if you want the app to seamlessly pick up exactly where it was after it was restarted, you’ll want to do [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches/about_the_ui_restoration_process)

Comment: but your ? too broad to answer

Comment: Thanks to every one. I have edited this question again. I have added 3 more points. Kindly check and guide me

Comment: @Rob Can u guide me?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can u guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

u will need to save the application state and restore state when the app will relaunch.

try this 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/1395-state-restoration-tutorial-getting-started